# How to read only one line from JSON with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have JSON like this:

```
data {
  data1 = 'test',
  data2 = 'test2',
  data3 = 'test3'
}
```

and I have this data in my $scope.myJsonData.

How I can read what is inside data2? Is the best way to do this to it like this `{{ myJsonData.data[1] }}` or is there better ways to do this? Can I somehow read it with name (data2)?

Sorry if this was bad explanation, my english isn't very good. Ask if you need more information.

Comment: That is not valid json.. It should be `data1: 'test`', etc (with colons)

Comment: @Jis0 I think you should learn the fundamentals of Javascript before you try to get into AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data1, data2` etc are keys, so to access data2's value simply write

```
var myvalue = data.data2
```

Answer (score 1):

At first the json data which you had given is not correct json format,

I think your json is

```
data { 
'data1' : 'test',
'data2' : 'test2',
'data3' : 'test3' 
}
```

You can read the data2 like this

```
myJsonData.data.data2
```